# Alarm is not Fired when i set time in android

Tags: android

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    DBhelper dbhelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
        dbhelper = new DBhelper(ctx);

        String[] ID = dbhelper.FetchAllID();
        String[] time = dbhelper.FetchAlltime();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, 22);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        for (int k = 0; k < ID.length; k++) {

            intent = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class);
            // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, k,
                    intent, 0);
            // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, sdl,
                    pendingIntent);

            intentArray.add(pendingIntent);

        }

    }
```

This is My code for Alarm i want to set Alarm for particular time But its not trigger when time completed i have use calendar and i have set to fire 4:20 minute Pm for that i have add in Hour 16 and in minute 20 but its not triggered when Device time reach 4.20 Pm please tell me what i doing mistake

Comment: Are you complaining that the Alarm isn't delivered on the **exact** time?

Comment: yes its Not delivered i dont know where am doing mistake

Comment: Not delivered **at all** or not delivered on the **exact time**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl,
                pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Shaen can we set Time Multiple time ?

Comment: Yes, you can re-set the time once it's due, using the same PendingIntent. OR you can set multiple alarrms at once (by using a different PendingIntent for each of them)

Comment: i have time in database 2.40 Pm  time i want to set Alarm at 2.40 then the time which i have set in Calendar is Correct Or Wrong Coz its not firing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have registered the broadcast receiver in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".SchedulerEventReceiver"/>
```

And provide alarm permission as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: Hmmmm .. see if your alarm is getting set at all - 
adb shell dumpsys alarm

Comment: Also, I hope you are not "killing" the app or rebooting your device after setting the alarm and before it is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to the tell the Calendar what day is today.

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Date date = new Date();

  calendar.setTime(date);   its Is ok

Comment: calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
  calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, 57);
  calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
  long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 i have use this now but still Not Fire